# Undefined reference C++?

Tags: c++

New to c++, and trying to use a file our professor made for us and I can't use any of the functions it provides heres the code that gives an Undefined reference. I didn't include the function implementations but they again were provided so they are correct. I'm using codeblocks and all three files are in my sources folder. What is causing this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#include "random.h"


int main()
{

cout<< random_instance(6,2.5,1);
return 0;
}
```

this is the random.h

```
#ifndef RANDOM_H
#define RANDOM_H

#define TWO_PI 6.2831853071795864769252866

double * random_instance( int length, const double mu, const double sigma = 1 );
double gaussian_rand( const double mu, const double sigma );

#endif /* defined(RANDOM_H) */
```

Comment: Is random.cpp also in the sources folder?

Comment: How are you compiling it? You're likely forgetting to compile/link with the code your instructor provided.

Comment: yes it is, they are in different folders, both of which are in the sources folder if that matters

Comment: You may this question and at-least one of its answers enlightening: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @WhozCraig Sure, they will.

Answer (score 0):

The definition for `random_instance` is missing.

You should probably compile and link `random.cpp` too which should contain the definitions for the functions declared in `random.h`, maybe something like this:

```
g++ path/to/main.cpp path/to/random.cpp
```

In Code::Blocks there's probably a section somewhere where you can choose the files to compile and link.